# Antonyms of "shortlisted"

Tags: word-choice, antonyms

Are there any opposites of shortlisted?

Currently, I am developing an application where candidates are `shortlisted` and I, the user, want to be `un-shortlisted`.

I googled but no word was found. If there is no word related to it, then what will be the best word to select and reject a candidate other than select and reject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would simply say, *"I would like to be taken off your shortlist"*. If you are looking for a single word for your application, one of [*unlist*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unlist), [*delist*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/delist), or simply, [*remove*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/remove) might do. You could also use *remove from shortlist* for additional clarity.

Comment: fair enough to go ahead with `delist`